Отправка команд на лазерный гравер JPT через USB
купил я значит лазерный гравер JPT m7 30W плата bjjcz, у которого драйвера я ставил с флешки в комплекте, и также было ПО EzCad2. У меня есть программка для печати на принтере написанная на C#, и хочется чтобы гравировка тоже была возможна через мою программу, хотелось бы просто принять текст строку на входе и выгравировать эту строку на металле например, но проблема в том что я не могу отправить команду на гравер тк, COM порта в нем нет, только USB порт, + кастомные дрова следовательно библиотек в C# на этот гравер нет. Помогите пожалуйста связаться с гравером через драйвера (lmcv2u - название дров) и отправить туда команду сокрее всего на GCODE.

Ломать проприетарный код тут врядле кто станет, да и запрещено это правилами сообщества. Да и ломать драйвер совсем гадкое дело даже для тех людей кто собственно профисионально занимаеться взломом/отладкой драйверов. Потому что те кто ломают драйвера либо это делают для поддержки крутых легаси устройств, либо для взлома дорогого ПО или игр с защитой по железу.
Как вариант, могу предложить например сломать саму программу EzCAD 2. Простой вариант это отправка пользовательских сообщений (SendMessage) и счтывание текста (GetWindowText). Сложный вариант - посмотреть видосов по CheatEngine и напрямую читать/писать память приложения.
Если ты прям готов к хардкору и хочешь реально написать порт к драйверу. То это намного проще сделать опять-же через EzCAD, просматривая через ту-же Ghidra или IDA Pro что она делает с драйвером. Куда звонит, что вызывает, какие параметры.
Ибо USB драйвер может работать как любое из перечисленных утройств

Виртуальный TTL порт. (то что ты называешь COM портом)
Виртуальный дисковый накопитель.
Виртуальный сетевой драйвер.
Виртуальный стековый драйвер. (отеправка/приём простых кодовых комманд)

Причём например некоторые извращенцы объеденяют возможные варианты. Так как USB может на лету менять тип и количество устройств. Как с протоколом FTP - где 21й порт для комманд, а по запросу он отрывает порт для файлов.
Если реального TTL нету, первое на что я бы обратил внимание это - NamedPipes это так называемые базовые устройства ввода-вывода у которых есть STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR если твоя программа открывает файл под названием похожим на \\\\.\\pipe\\SampleDriver то в 99% случаев это и есть протокол общения клиенского приложения с драйвером.
DiskMon for Windows v2.02 тебе в помощь.
Кстати винда ещё позволяет использовать пайпы USB в так называемом закрытом режиме, USB Pipes что счастья тебе не добавит вовсе.

WireShark умеет USB перехватывать. Но это для продвинутых.

@MaximTimakov поддерживаю, тоже удобная штука для ковыряния в чужих мозгах :)

usb shark пробовал уже, но там за 10 секунд гдето 30к обменов между хостом и устройством и то что мне надо было я найти попросту не смог. Наверно буду искать просто паленую плату управления с открытым сдк или типа того
